# How to calculate rendering time in WebGL? Looks like I am calculating it wrongly

Tags: browser, webgl, rendering, interactive

I am running an interactive browser based WebGL volume rendering. With mouse when I make interaction the function *drawVolume()* is called. To measure rendering time, I take time stamp at *start* and *end*. The *difference* gives me rendering time. 
Currently I am running it on two machines: client and Server

Following are the observations:

*Server-machine: [NVIDIA GeForce GTX970]* *Render_time* is approximately less than *2ms*. Interaction is faster.

*Client-machine:[NVIDIA Quadro K600]* *Render_time* is approximately *10-11ms* . Interactive display is slower, frames are updated slowly. And sometimes the display drivers stop working and display goes off. I need to restart the system.

I do not know, if this method is right for calculating rendering time. Somehow I feel, eventhough, the code is exectuted, at hardware level the rendered image is not yet displayed on browser window. How to get to know the respective frame updated for the respective interaction. If I get that status then maybe I can calculate correctly the rendering time.

```
drawVolume = function()
{
    start3 = new Date().getTime();  

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.fboBackCoord);
    gl.shaderProgram = gl.shaderProgram_BackCoord;
    gl.useProgram(gl.shaderProgram);
    gl.clearDepth(-50.0);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);
    drawCube(gl,cube);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.shaderProgram = gl.shaderProgram_RayCast;
    gl.useProgram(gl.shaderProgram);
    gl.clearDepth(50.0);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.fboBackCoord.tex);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.vol_tex);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.tf_tex);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uBackCoord"), 0);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uVolData"), 1);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uTransferFunction"), 2);
    //Set Texture
    drawCube(gl,cube);

    end3 = new Date().getTime();
    render_time=end3-start3;
    console.log(render_time);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU/GPU interaction is asynchronous, this is implemented using driver internal command buffers in which all issued commands are buffered, thus there is no guarantee that your commands are executed by the time you call `new Date().getTime()`(using `Date.now()` and caching the uniform locations would be better btw.).

In most scenarios it's not desirable to force/wait for execution of given commands, however it is possible using [`finish`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.11)([man page](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFinish.xml)) which introduces a sync point and blocks CPU side execution until all commands are executed. However as pointed out in [gmans answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191845/128511) this is not only measuring execution time of previously issued commands but also the time it takes to stall the pipeline.

Ideally one would use the [`EXT_disjoint_timer_query`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_disjoint_timer_query/) extension that allows to measure execution time of given commands without stalling the pipeline, sadly though as of now(Oct 2016) this extension isn't available/exposed in pretty much any browser.

Comment: [As explained elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191845/128511) `finish` will not give you accurate timing. This is doubly true on tiled architectures.

Comment: So glfinish option won't work in WebGL and EXT_disjoint_timer_query  is not yet available in browser, so, isn't there any other method to calculate the _approximate rendering time_?

Comment: Its not that `finish` *"won't work in WebGL"* its just not what you think it is regardless of platform, read *gmans* answer for detailed information. Otherwise no, there isn't, at least not on application level.

Comment: I have found some WebGL profiling tools, these are very helpful. Here is the link: [link] (http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/webgl-debugging-and-profiling-tools/).  I am looking into how accurate the tools are.